# Woo commerce remove product review field. show only ratings

Tags: wordpress

I want to accept only rating for my products from only registered users. 
I don't want review fields. I tried to remove field but this field has some validation. and I don't know how to remove this validation.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the site ? maybe a CSS solution will be suitable to hide it

Comment: How you are using review instead of tab?

Comment: For validation remove you need to show us the html code

Comment: @AkshayShah this is WordPress default form  I haven't added any custom code in this

Comment: I checked the url and you can remove validation with use of jquery or you need to find that from which file it is populating.

Comment: with jquery i removed all the fields.

Comment: it have some php vaidation i tried jquery not working its giving me php error

Comment: sendinf me to this page http://animalcare.etrafficgroup.com.au/wp-comments-post.php and page displays error "ERROR: please type a comment."

Comment: hii ,if i remove this code in wordpress comments .php its working but if wordpress version gets updated it will get added again right if ( '' == $comment_content ) {
  return new WP_Error( 'require_valid_comment', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: please type a comment.' ), 200 );
 }

Answer (score 0):

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab', 98 );
    function wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['reviews']);
    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: this will remove review tab. I don't want to remove the tab. I just want to remove the text field in form i just want to accept ratings

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_comment_form_field($comment_form) {

$comment_form['comment_field'] = '';

if ( wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
    $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . ( wc_review_ratings_required() ? '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
        <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
        <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
        <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
        <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
        <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
        <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
    </select></div>';
}


return $comment_form;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', 'remove_comment_form_field');

add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');
```

Comment: Make sure to add a description of what your code does!